# I am trying to run liquidbaseapplication using springboot and i have got an error while running the application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-03-28T15:24:49.079+05:30 ERROR 21580 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Cannot find parser that supports true
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at io.neel.demoliquidbase.DemoLiquidbaseApplication.main(DemoLiquidbaseApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnknownChangelogFormatException: Cannot find parser that supports true
    at liquibase.parser.ChangeLogParserFactory.getParser(ChangeLogParserFactory.java:55) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:404) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:393) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$update$1(Liquibase.java:249) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:180) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:189) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:179) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:158) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:2447) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:236) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:221) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:328) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:283) ~[liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
    ... 18 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

i want to make the program run without any error

Comment: What have you tried? The error is telling you that there's a problem with your configuration of Liquibase's change log but you've told us nothing about that.

Comment: what configurations can you specifically say so i can write those here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.